# Install Cabal-dev with cygwin On windows 7

Tags: haskell, cygwin, cabal, yesod

I'm trying to do this:

```
cabal install cabal-dev
```

I have the lastest haskell platform installed and cygwin my path.

I get this far:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading network-2.3.2.0...
Configuring network-2.3.2.0...
```

and then eventually I get a sh.exe.stackdump

```
Stack trace:

Frame     Function  Args
00289218  6102F97B  (00289218, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
00289508  6102F97B  (6119FE20, 00008000, 00000000, 611A1C8F)
0028A538  6100652C  (611DC6AC, 0028A564, 765A1148, 000002B4)
0028A558  61006568  (611DC6AC, 611DC75D, 00000000, 00000000)
0028A598  61076E70  (61203020, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028A5D8  61077007  (0028A600, 0028A5E0, 00000000, 00000000)
0028A768  61078179  (00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
End of stack trace
```

process explorer tells me that this is trying to run:

```
"sh" "configure" "--with-compiler=ghc" "--prefix=C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Roaming\cabal" "--with-gcc=C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.2.0.0\mingw\bin\gcc.exe"
```

From here:

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\network-2.3.2.0-7028\network-2.3.2.0\
```

**How do I get this installed?**

It tried

```
runghc Setup.hs configure
```

from the network-2.3.2.0 folder as well with the same result.

***Update:***

I got it to install with (thanks!)

```
cabal install --constraint="network installed" cabal-dev
```

But I can't figure out how to use it.

```
> cabal-dev install && yesod
cabal-dev is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I'm trying to go through [this tutorial for YESOD](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Yesod-tutorial-for-newbies/), but not getting very far

Comment: I don't know what is  cabal or ghc but considering config is a shell script I am wondering if the script is tripping on the backslashes and spacey paths. Try with whatever `cygpath -dma` gives for `"C:\\Users\\Adam\\AppData\\Roaming\\cabal"` and `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Haskell Platform\\2012.2.0.0\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe"`

Comment: The latest platform has network-2.3.0.13 - this should be sufficient for `cabal-dev` so force `cabal install` to use the version you already have installed rather than try to update it (building network is a little challenging on Windows - you need to either use MinGW / MSYS or cross compile as per the instructions on Neil Mitchell's blog). Unfortunately, as I don't use `cabal install` I can't remember what the flag is to avoid updating packages you already have installed.

Comment: Use `cabal install --constraint="network installed" cabal-dev`. That ought to work. To not have any unpleasant surprises, it might be a good idea to run that with the `--dry-run` flag first.

Comment: Not that this explains the problem the OP is having installing network-2.3.20, but I don't think cabal-dev-0.9.1 compiles under ghc-6.4.1 (as included in the current Haskell Platform).

Comment: cabal install --constraint="network installed" cabal-dev worked

Comment: For your new problem, the first suspect is that it's not in the path. Then you'd need to add the directory it was installed in (something like `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin` I guess) to the `%PATH%` environment variable.

Comment: is there supposed to be a cabal-dev, I have a fake-ghc-cabal-dev.exe in cabal\bin, so adding to path doesn't help

Comment: @Adam I have the same problem - cabal-dev.exe is missing. Have you made any headway with this?

Comment: @drozzy yes, I did, I believe the solution was to get the version of cabal-dev from git hub.  hackage one that cabal install pulls has issues.

Comment: @drozzy See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442588/install-cabal-dev-on-windows-7/13456311#13456311

Comment: @Adam Thanks for the follow up, I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments note, you shouldn't reinstall `network`, and instead should force `cabal-dev` to install with the current `network` package.

Comment: As @Adam points out, this works, but the cabal-dev.exe is still missing on our (Windows-based) systems. My `cabal/bin` directory only has `cabal.exe`, `fake-ghc-cabal-dev.exe` and `ghc-pkg-6_8-compat.exe`.

Comment: @drozzy take a look at the .cabal file. clearly the no-cabal-dev flag is getting flipped somehow. i'd just remove the test for it from the executable stanza and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I got it installed within sandbox via Git Bash(which is a MINGW32 shell) using:

```
cabal install network --configure-option --build=i386-unknown-mingw32 --configure-option --host=i686-pc-mingw32
```

Of course you can add `--enable-shared` if you want to enable dynamic linking.