# Install Cabal-dev on windows 7

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

I'm trying to install Cabal-dev on windows 7.

I've managed to get past the problem with not being able to build network by using this:

```
cabal install --constraint="network installed" cabal-dev
```

However then I get this:

```
>cabal install --constraint="network installed" cabal-dev 
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: cabal-dev-0.9.1
trying: cabal-dev-0.9.1:-no-cabal-dev
trying: network-2.3.1.0/installed-489...
rejecting: parsec-3.1.3/installed-62e... (conflict: network =>
parsec==3.1.3/installed-c65...)
rejecting: parsec-3.1.3/installed-c65... (conflict: parsec =>
mtl==2.1.2/installed-533..., cabal-dev-0.9.1:no-cabal-dev => mtl>=1.1 && <2.1)
rejecting: parsec-3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.1.0.1, 2.1.0.0,
2.0 (conflict: network => parsec==3.1.3/installed-c65...)
```

Comment: Try the latest version [from the author's repo](https://github.com/creswick/cabal-dev).

Answer (score 1):

Mikhail Glushenkov's recommendation worked

I cloned the [git repo for cabal-dev](https://github.com/creswick/cabal-dev) and then build it like this:

```
runhaskell -isrc admin/bootstrap.hs
```

then I added

```
{windowspath ..}\cabal-dev\cabal-dev\bin
```

to my path and everything is working.

I can now run cabal-dev install in my yesod folder get yesod working finally.

Comment: Actually, it didn't, as Yesod says it can't read the cabal-dev config file bc they were build with a different version of GHC.  I only have one version of GHC installed.

Comment: Well, this actually worked for me (but then I didn't need Yesod). Thanks for the tip on how to clone the repo and compile it.